# how to add favicon with symfony 6

Tags: symfony, favicon, symfony6

Good morning to you all,

I'd like to ask you for help because I don't understand where my problem with adding a favicon with Symfony 6 comes from.

I have two codes in mind, this one

```
<link rel="icon"
      href="{{ '/images/' ~ 'favicon.jpg' }}"
      type="image/x-icon"
      src="" />
```

as well as this one

```
<link rel="icon"
      href="{{ asset('/images/' ~ 'favicon.jpg') }}"
      type="image/x-icon"
      src="" />
```

None of the codes work.

I even get this error in Symfony when I put assets in my code, and I use yarn.

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "C:\wamp64\www\projet-conrad-angela/public/build/manifest.json" does not exist. Did you forget to build the assets with npm or yarn?").
```

```
<link rel="icon"
      href="{{ asset('/images/' ~ 'favicon.jpg') }}"
      type="image/x-icon"
      src="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    {# Run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` to start using Symfony UX #}
```

If you have a solution, I would be delighted to help. Thank you.

Comment: So, does `/images/favicon.jpg` exist?

Comment: @JovanPerovic Hi, yes, it exists, indeed.

Comment: And what about the `/build/manifest.json`? Argument that you pass to `asset()` function, should ideally be present within the file, and if it does not - it will be used as specified…

Comment: @JovanPerovic I d'ont have this file, i don't find it.

Comment: That means that you did not run Webpack Encore (either `yarn dev` or `yarn watch`). Try running it and it should show up

Comment: @JovanPerovic, thank you for your last answer. i dit it but the response was :  ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                      00:18:33

Module build failed: Module not found:
I am going nuts :/

Comment: Can you update the question with your `webpack.encore.js` file? And can you show us your directory where you original assets are stored?

Comment: @JovanPerovic I have found that i don't have this file webpack.encore.js That's so odd.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `webpack.config.js`... you should have one in the root directory of your project.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to add a file named `favicon.ico` to your public directory.

Comment: `public` directory is being built by Symfony and is not supposed to be changed manually. Your solution is a bad hack.

Comment: @NikolaStojiljković Not all content in the public directory is generated. Take for example the `index.php` file. It is perfectly acceptable to manually add some files to the public directory. Adding the favicon.ico to the root of the server will make it accessible for every page rendered by your web server, which can be quite convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="{{ asset('favicon.jpg') }}" />
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#absolute-url
or

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="{{ absolute_url('favicon.jpg') }}" />
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#reference-twig-function-asset

and you can combine both:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="{{ absolute_url(asset('favicon.jpg')) }}" />
```